# DNS resolving based on client IP

Tags: dns, bind, hosts-file

I want to configure bind/write driver that resolves DNS requests based on the ip address of the client.

We want to unify the domain names of all test environments for our web application.
Instead of having many domains like `test.mysite.com`, `qa.mysite.com`, etc for different staging environments we want only to have `www.mysite.com` and make it configurable which test environment it "points" to.

To accomplish this I am thinking of providing web interface for configuring which test environment has to be used. DNS requests than should be answered based on this configuration.

Do you think something like this is doable with bind or other dns server? And how does it compare to writing client application that modifies the local hosts file?

Comment: I think this will quickly fall apart when you get clients coming to test it from other IPs. Clients will want to generally consume production data, and _some_ Test environments. Clients might not have (should not have) access to all test environments. It would also get quite annoying when comparing environments, or ensuring that a dangerous operation is actually targetting the environment you think it should be targetting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PowerDNS](http://www.powerdns.com) with the [pipe backend](http://downloads.powerdns.com/documentation/html/backends-detail.html#PIPEBACKEND-PROTOCOL) to return different IP addresses dependent on the client's IP address.

Comment: Yes, nice software and there are several ways to write a backend (the pipe being the simplest).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [location](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns-data.html) facility in [djbdns](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html). Your task in making the web interface is writing out (and parsing, if you don't want to have a separate database backend) the DNS data files in the right format.

Here's another resource on a related topic, "split horizon DNS". It's not the same as your question, but the ideas in the article can be adapted to your needs: http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-split-horizon.html